# Синтаксис Makefile

Tags: makefile

Разбираюсь с Makefile и не могу понять, что получает данная переменная?

```
PROJECT_DIR := $(shell dirname $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разберем это изнутри. Есть некий список файлов `$MAKEFILE_LIST`. функция [lastword](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) берет с него последнее (крайнее правое слово). Слова - это просто строки, разделенные пробелами.

Дальше идет [abspath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) которая, грубо говоря, нормализирует путь - убирает с него косвенности (в виде точек) и подобное. Но она не проверяет, есть ли такой файл/путь на самом деле и не трогает симлинки (то есть, не разворачивает их).

Дальше к этому применяется [dirname](https://linuxhandbook.com/dirname/), которая извлекает имя каталога, отбрасывая имя файла в самом конце. Но это команда баша (шела), поэтому там применяется явный его вызов. И то, что получится, записывается в PROJECT_DIR.

Осталось выяснить, а что такое [MAKEFILE_LIST](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-makefiles_002c-and-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-variable). Это такая переменная, которая содержит имена всех makefile, которые make нашел и парсит. И там же есть уточнение

> Thus, if the first thing a makefile does is examine the last word in this variable, it will be the name of the current makefile.

то есть, если этот код находится в самом начале, то `lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)` содержит имя текущего Makefile.

Теперь делаем вывод - скорее всего эта строка сохраняет в PROJECT_DIR каталог, в котором собственно находится текущий Makefile. (Если этот код находится в правильном месте)